# Algorithm for pattern string replacements (php + regexp)

Tags: php, algorithm

I have several hundreds of special code templates, like:

```php
array(
    'mask'   => '98-###(###)',
    'detect' => '98-\d\d\d(\d\d\d)',
), 
...
```

And input strings (only digits), what is a best way to detect and format (replacing `#` to digits from input string) codes?  My [algorithm](https://gist.github.com/Bogdaan/f6292f69d5d3a0a47821) works, but its very slow (I need format codes for each request) - Can anyone see how it could be improved:

```php
<?php
class PCode
    {
    private static $vector = array (
        0 => array (
            'detect' => '247\\d\\d\\d\\d',
            'mask'   => '+247-####',
    ), // <<<<< more codes here

    );
    /**
    *
    * @param unknown $phs
    * @return string
    */
    public static function format($phn)
    {
        $result = $phn;
        foreach(self::$vector as $row)
        {
            if(preg_match('/'.$row['detect'].'/s', $phn))
            {
                $reverse = array_reverse( str_split($phn) );
                $reverseMask = array_reverse( str_split($row['mask']) );
                $newresult = array();
                $ridx = 0;
                foreach($reverseMask as $k)
                {
                    if($k=='#')
                    {
                        $newresult[] = $reverse[$ridx];
                        $ridx++;
                    }
                    else
                        $newresult[] = $k;
                }
                $result = implode('', array_reverse( $newresult ));
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: `preg_match` is an expensive call. Try to avoid making it in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

`$maskes = array(
    '\b98-\d{3}\(\d{3}\)\b' => '98-###(###)',
    '\b247\d{4}\b' => '+247-####',
);
preg_replace(
    array_keys($maskes),
    array_values($maskes),
    $text
);`

But if your phone numbers are stored in a DB, perhaps you can store the country. Then you apply the localized pattern for each phone number. See tools on http://geonames.org
Moreover think how you can cache the result when your code is too slow.

Comment: thanks, its phone codes, but with diffrencies (custom format required)